# Non-Trivial ODE Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I’ve been looking at non-trivial solutions of ODEs. I found one and have problems with it.

$y’(x)=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{y(x)}$

$y(0)=0$

I know the one of the solutions of this ODE is

$y(x) = \frac{x^2}{64}$

Are there any other non-trivial solutions to this ODE. Thanks

Comment: Your solution is wrong.  Just substitute it in to see that.  If $y = x^2/64$, then $y' = x/32$.

Comment: $y(x)$ should be something with $x^{3/2}$ your answer is not correct.

Comment: I'm guessing the DE should be $y'=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: Yes I have corrected the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation is separable (and autonomous),

$$\frac{y'}{2\sqrt y}=\frac18,$$

giving by definite integration

$$\sqrt y-\sqrt 0=\frac{x-0}8$$ or $$y=\frac{x^2}{64}$$ which is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is an antiderivative problem. The fundamental theorem of integral calculus asserts that
$$y(x)=\int_0^x\tfrac14\sqrt{ t\mkern1mu}\mkern3mu\mathrm dt=\tfrac14\tfrac23t^{3/2}\bigg|_0^x{}=\tfrac16 x^{3/2}.$$

Comment: Why don't you use the given initial condition ?

Comment: This answer is correct for the original question and equation +1  @User123456789

Comment: @Aryadeva: I don't agree, the solution does not have an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Bernard didnt' apply the initial condition simply. But his answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I mentioned the general solution; but you're right, I misinterpreted the O.P.'s question

Comment: @Aryadeva: I don't call correct an answer that answers another question.